# Will limiting the result set in the where clause improve the performance of group by and having?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I have a MySQL table with over 25 million rows. So to prevent bringing down the entire DB, I don’t want to do any queries which will cause temp tables to get created on disk, such as an order by on an unindexed column.

So if the table has the following columns…

```
 employee_id
 first_name
 last_name
 hire_date
 manager_id
```

And let’s say I want to see those managers who have 3 or more employees working for them like so (let's assume manager_id has no index)..

```
select count(*), manager_id from employee group by manager_id  having count(id) > 3
```

Would it help the performance of this query, if I restricted the result set to only those employees hired after 2016....

```
select count(*), manager_id from employee where hire_date > ‘2016-01-01’ 
group by manager_id having count(id) > 3
```

Let's assume hire_date also has no index. Would that additional where clause help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, restricting the rows in the `WHERE` clause means there will be fewer rows to group, and some groups won't even show up because the rows that would be in that group will already be filtered out.

The `GROUP BY` will probably create a temporary table in your query. But at least it will be a smaller temp table because there will be fewer groups. The way to avoid the temp table is to make a query scan in index order by an index on `manager_id`.

MySQL will be able to avoid the temp table if it can be assured that it's scanning in order by `manager_id`, so it can count the rows in each group more easily, assuming that it's scanning each group contiguously. In other words, when it reaches the last row for a given `manager_id`, it knows there can be no more rows further on for that same `manager_id`. Therefore it doesn't need to keep a tally of the count per manager_id. It can just output each count per manager_id as it finishes scanning each group of rows.

But you might find that an index on `hire_date` has greater benefit. If that condition can avoid scanning most of the table by starting at rows where `hire_date > '2016-01-01'`, then the cost of the temp table might be less than the cost of the table-scan.

There's no way to make a query that scans by an index on `manager_id` and also scans by an index on `hire_date`. Which strategy is better depends on how many rows in your table matching different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can definitely help if the amount of data reduces significantly due to the where clause.

Though there is no alternative to trying this out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Folly.

I can show you a 10-row table and a query (with `JOIN`, but no `GROUP BY`) that will consume a terabyte of temp space on disk.

My point is, there is no simple way to prevent a rogue query from "crashing the system".

In your "hire-date" fix, what if a manager 2 employees before 2016 and 2 after?  Your "improved" query would fail to find their manager.

Having `INDEX(manager_id)` makes *some* difference, but still there will be a "full index scan", which is only marginally better than a "full table scan".

Adding the hire_date clause would not necessarily help.  In particular, `INDEX(hire_date)` is unlikely to help *at all*.  Even `INDEX(hire_date, manager_id)` (but not the other order) would help *some*.

And that is only a partial analysis of that relatively simple query.  What about the universe of other queries??  Folly.

One thing that will help:  Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.